# How does this function work?

Tags: swift2

I was learning to code in swift using a resource and there I saw this function which reverses the character given in the parameter. 
Here is the code:

```
func reverseIt(s: String) -> String {
    var rst = ""
    for char in s.characters {
       rst = "\(char)" + rst
    }
    return rst
}
```

I just want to know how did it manage to reverse it, because i don't se anything specific in here which does that

Comment: You're starting out with an empty string adding each character in the string to the front of the empty string.  You wrote it, what don't you understand?

Comment: Print out rst inside the for loop, then you'll see.

Comment: I didn't write it, I just saw it somewhere and typed it in here.

Comment: "I came up with this function" this in your question implies that you wrote the function.  You should probably edit your question.

Comment: Still, I need a little bit of more clarification.. Please??

Comment: @JAL sorry, corrected it..

Comment: Copy the code into an Xcode project and use the built-in **debugger**.  Set a breakpoint, single-step through the code, inspect the variables, then you'll understand quickly how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step through it in your mind using "Hello" as an example:

The first time, `rst` is empty, and becomes `"H" + rst` or `"H"` (since `rst` is empty).

The next time, the 2nd character `"e"` is taken, and `rst` becomes `"e" + rst` which is `"e" + "H"` or `"eH"`. You can see where this is going.

Comment: Oooohhh... I got it now!!! Thank you so much pal. Pretty much a common sense thing but still thank you so Much man!!!

Comment: You're very welcome. Yes, common sense is the answer you're looking for ;-) Should help you answer a lot of questions for yourself! Btw, now that you get it, the other answers should make sense to you too.

Comment: Yeah, they certainly do!! Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0):

The function is very easy to follow , just see this line `rst = "\(char)" + rst`.

Initially is an empty string and then each character (obtained for the variable in the `for` and then using string interpolation) is appended at the beginning of the string in each iteration of the `for` statement.

I hope this help you.

Comment: But why not in the correct order. For example why it doesn't print "hello" back in the correct order, but rather starting from the end?

Comment: @YousufEjazi007 There are several ways of reverse a string if you think a while, using a stack data structure, iterating from the end of the string, iterating from the beginning, etc. Of course every way has a cost (speaking in memory and efficiency). The way used in your question is just one of them, nothing more.

Comment: yeah, I did check it on the internet, there was even a whole encyclopedia page on how to reverse a given string. But still I don't quite get it. Can you try one more time to make it a bit simpler for me? I will be grateful..

Comment: @Why not correct order? Because correct order is `rst = rst + "\(char)"`. All you need to do is think it through. Simulate the code in your mind. If `rst` is `h` and you add the character `e` in front of it: `rst = "e" + rst`, why do you expect the new value of `rst` to be "he" instead of "eh"?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it reverses the string is due to the order of the code to the right of the assignment (=) operator. If the code were like this:

```
rst = rst + "\(char)"
```

then the results would not be reversed. If this doesn't help clear it up in your mind, then let's take it step by step. Using your code:

```
rst = "\(char)" + rst
```

for each pass of the for-in loop, the values would be like so:

```
first pass  - rst would get char ("h") + rst ("")     -> "h"
second pass - rst would get char ("e") + rst ("h")    -> "eh"
third pass  - rst would get char ("l") + rst ("eh")   -> "leh"
fourth pass - rst would get char ("l") + rst ("leh")  -> "lleh"
fifth pass  - rst would get char ("o") + rst ("lehh") -> "olleh"
```

Does this make it clear in your mind now?